# What does "夢を売る" mean? sell a dream?

Tags: words

I came across this sentence:
夢を売るのよ　スポーツって。

I guess here 夢を売る can't be translated to "dream selling", that just doesn't make sense.

So what does it mean anyways?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't make sense? People dreaming of being a star, and (other people) making money off of that, doesn't seem that far fetched when talking about sports.

Answer (score 3):

Would help if you provided more context.

> 夢を売る
>
> http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A4%A2%E3%82%92%E5%A3%B2%E3%82%8B
>
> http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%A4%A2%E3%82%92%E5%A3%B2

Looking it up in dictionaries provides no other meanings for the word. I'd guess that it's used in the context of "selling dreams", like how sports make kids and young adults dream of becoming professional athletes, and making it big.